# Mysqlite alphabetical sort misplacing strings beginning with alpha/beta

Tags: sql

I am trying to get a list of item names sorted alphabetically. The query works fine for most values, but there are a few values prefixed by the strings "alpha-" or "beta-" that are placed at the end (I assume something to do  with the actual alpha/beta characters?). Following is the query. Why is it interpreting those words that way, is there any way to change? Thanks!

```
sql = "SELECT id, long_name As name  FROM NAME_DB  WHERE long_name IS NOT NULL AND GOT_B_DATA =1 UNION SELECT id, alt_name As name FROM NAME_DB WHERE alt_name IS NOT NULL AND GOT_BDATA =1  ORDER BY name ASC"
```

Comment: Removed the conflicting product tags. Can you pls put the one back that you use?

Comment: If you mean that a string like "alpha-whatever" is placed after "something", this is impossible. There is something else that causing the problem. Post sample data and the results you get.

Comment: Well, it also does this in the table when sorting with that column so it seems to not just be the query